# Using Materials with Geometry Node Modifier

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

Since experementing with the newest Verison of Blender (2.92.0) I work heavily with the Geometry Nodes. But the documentation is very low quality. I was able to model different objects and join them together with the Geometry Node Modifier, to make a bigger model.

Now I have assigned Materials to the single Parts, so I have more control over everything. The Materials don't seem to be moved over with the Object Info node. Is there any way to get the Material to a new Object, only with Geometry Nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can do it in 3.0 Alpha with the Material assign node.

like this:

[image]

Comment: what version of Blender is this node in, I don't see it in 2.93.1, 3.0?

Comment: It is in 3.0 alpha

Comment: Okay in 3.0 it's in. But there is no option, if I still use 2.92 or 2.93.1?