# How can I set material to this geo node?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

How can I set material to this geo node ?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216192/using-materials-with-geometry-node-modifier

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE! Have you tried the node `Set Material`?

Comment: I’ve tried set material before group output but it didn’t work. Btw, I use blender 3.4